# calling an Asp.net MVC 3 action method that updates a database in a unit testing method

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

Coders,  I am in process of writing test cases for Asp.net MVC 3 project and I need call an action method that insert data into a database using Entity Framework. Here is the code for the action method:

```
//
    // POST: /School/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(School school)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Schools.Add(school);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(school);
    }
```

And here is the code for my test method:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void CreateNewSchool()
    {
        var schoolController = new SchoolController();
        var viewResult = schoolController.Index();

        //creating a school object
        School school = new School();
        school.Name = "OOO";

        //passing the school object to the action method
        schoolController.Create(school);

        //making sure that the model is not null
        Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult.Model);
    }
```

Notice, however, that I don’t check if the data were actually inserted in the database. I just check that the model of the view is not null. I do manually check the database using SQL server management studio.

The problem is though that when I call the action method in the test method to create/insert a record in the database nothing happened to the database. However, if I run the application and brows to the create page and try to create a new recorded then the record will be added to the database. So it appears to me that insertion to database happens only if I run the application and actually brows to the create page and hit the create button, but I cannot programmatically call the action method in the test method to insert a new record in the database. I have also debugged the test case and it did hit the db.SaveChanges(); line in the action method, but no changes were reflected in the database.

So, can someone explain to me why I am not able to insert a record by calling the action method in my test method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into how your `db` context is getting instantiated. In many cases, it is not desirable for unit tests to cause database round-trips, so people use strategies like mocking to prevent it. It might be something as simple as using a different connection string when you are running a unit test versus running it as an asp.net application.

Comment: after reading your answer, i debugged the project and after i have hit db.SaveChages() I checked the the db.Schools.Local.Count and it was 19! it seems like all the added schools objects are being stored in memory or somewhere else but not in the database. I am assuming that 19 is the number of times that i have tried to run the test cases. I was also able to dig through each object in the db.Schools.Local and they were exactly the objects that i was trying to insert in the db.

Comment: @ealshabaan: While debugging, check `db.Connection.ConnectionString`

Comment: apparently, the connection string is different than the one i have on my web.config!!! I had to manually set the connectionstring to my match my web.config

Comment: @ealshabaan: There is probably an App.config file in your test project folder. See if it has the connection string defined there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any validation on the school class?  I am guessing when you run it under the test environment that school is not valid and so ModelState.IsValid returns false and doesn't save.

Comment: "I have also debugged the test case and it did hit the db.SaveChanges(); line in the action method, but no changes were reflected in the database."